# Implementation of table-base result of PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am beginner in PL/SQL and should develop my project using 
pl/SQL. Indeed I am going to write all of my queries as stored procedures in a package and save them in the server. Also, I want to access to the stored procedure from out of PL/SQL editor environment, execute them and manipulate
the result of query which is written in the stored procedure. Now, I faced with a problem that I can not solve it. Indeed, I can not process the result of query of procedure. I have used two technics. For instance I have used a "SYS_REFCURSOR" as a output parameter and executed the procedure. While I do not have enough knowledge to access the output. Totally, I can not access the data saved in the "SYS_REFCURSOR" parameter from my program.
Besides, I have Introduced a new type and a table of it, in order to make a container for saving result of query. While, Also I can not access to the output data of query.
Could you please help me to solve this problem.?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What language you use at client side?

Comment: I use Jaspersoft Studio which is a report generator based on java.

Comment: You should probably tag this question with whatever technology you are having the problem with. As a PL/SQL / database guy there's nothing for me to answer here.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9962622/how-to-call-stored-procedure-that-returns-sys-refcursor-from-ireport-4-5-1